# git forgot to add new changes last added changes commited

Tags: git, github

I had a file in which I made some changes and added the file in git using the command

```
git add file-name
```

and not commited it.

Later on I made a few more changes in the file and forgot to add those changes and did commit in git using

```
git commit -m "added file-name"
```

Now how can I add the last changes as well in git. Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`add` the file again and do a `git commit --amend`

the `--amend` flag tells git-commit to not create a new commit, instead, just edit the last one. This will edit your local history

**BE CAREFUL**. You should only do this if you didn't push your repo to a remote (if you didn't do `git push` )

Comment: what if I also pushed the same?

Comment: Then you make a new commit instead with a message along the lines of "Oops, silly me! I meant to include these changes as well."

Answer (score 0):

In addition to git --amend, mentioned previously, you can also use git rebase -i, which I happen to love. This feature allows you to reorder, squash, and reedit commits. When I find that I have neglected to add some data to a commit, I add the forgotten material to the index, commit with a dummy commit message, and then immediately run git rebase -i to squash the new commit "into" the old.

But of course, as with any form of history rewriting, this is only possibly if your previous commits have not been shared (either via a push by you or a pull from you).